# How can I use two bootstrap modal using mvc 5, second bootstrap document ready not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-modal

I'm using mvc 5. I have a view witch calls a modal bootstrap "delete confimation"

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('.delete').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //Update the item to delete id so our model knows which one to delete
                var id = $(this).data('id');
                $('#item-to-delete').val(id);
            });

            $('#btn-delete-error').click(function () {
                var id = $('#item-to-delete').val();
                //Call our delete actionresult and pass over this id           
                $.get("@Url.Action("Delete", "ErrorManagement")", { id: id });
                ajax = false;
            });  
});
```

This is the part of the controller:

Like this:

```
public ActionResult Delete(string id)
    {
        using (_db = new someEntities())
        {
            alerts a = new alerts();
            a = (from al in _db.alerts where al.idAlerts.Equals(id) select al).FirstOrDefault();
            if (!a.Equals(null))
            {
                _db.alerts.Remove(a);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return View("_DialogConfirmErrorMessageDelete");
            }
                return View("Index");                
        }            
    }
```

_DialogConfirmErrorMessageDelete is another boostrap modal Complete with htmlLike this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#myModal2').modal({
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false
            })
            $("#myModal2").modal('show');

            $('#btn-back-to-error-page').click(function () {
                location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "ErrorManagement")';
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md">
                <div class="le-contenu-du-retour">
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade in">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p class="text-warning">
                                        <small>
                                            Your error message has been deleted successfully.<br />
                                        </small>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" id="btn-back-to-error-page" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Go to main page</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- Modal -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller work and everyting is deleted.
The problem is that the document ready in _DialogConfirmErrorMessageDelete never gets fired to confirm delete.
If I use:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete","ErrorManagement", new { id = item.idAlerts }, new { @class = "unit-tag" })
```

Without passing thru the first boostrap modal to confirm delete, it works fine.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After searching and trying I solved my problem adding a litle ajax in the document ready function as fallow...

```
$('#btn-delete-error').click(function () {
        var id = $('#item-to-delete').val();
        //Call our delete actionresult and pass over this id           
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Errormanagement")',
            data: { id: id },
            success: function () {
                location.href = '@Url.Action("ConfirmErrorMessageDelete", "ErrorManagement")';
            }
        });
```

Thanks